# Override hover style for specific rows of table

Tags: html, css, angularjs

We have a generic css style defined like this:

```
.table-container table tr:hover td {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

This is used for all tables across application. However, I have to override it for a particular table on specific rows. I am attaching new css style at each `<tr class=‘edited’>` with this definition:

```
.edited {
  background-color: #f8cbad;
}
```

But, when hovering over the row, it is using generic hover style, and I am not able to override it.

Can you please suggest how to override it so that I see same background color as edited style even on hovering the row?

I tried with following and tweaking, but didn’t work.

```
.table-container table tr:hover .edited td {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

Comment: try background-color: #f8cbad !important; ?

Comment: Go read up on [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of declarations in CSS.

Comment: If you want to override a CSS rule you have to think about the highest order of the CSS Rule itself. A more specific CSS Rule will always override the simpler one. Example: `.edited` will be overridden by `.wrapper div .edited` and so on. A simple shurtcut could be to add `!important` to the end of an Rule.

Comment: Adding !important for ‘edited’ class does not work. When hovering, still generic hover style is applied.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have figured out after some trial. Answering to help others:
Defining hover for the specific style class did the trick:

```
.edited {
  background-color: #f8cbad;
}
.edited:hover {
  background-color: #f8cbad !important;
}
```